# Principal moment of inertia for a rotating body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

My major is not in physics.

I am reading the following paper:   (my problem is simple and not related with any optimization)

http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2841    (p.5~p.6)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Suppose

1. The body angular velocity is $\Omega(t_0) = [\omega \ \  0 \ \ 0]^T$, $\omega$ is a constant.
2. Torque free motion

---

My problem:

> In this case, can I obtain the result:  $I_1=I_2 = I_3$ since $\dot{\omega}_i=0$?  It is bit odd since the paper assume $I_1\geq I_2\geq I_3$, so the only possibility is "$=$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot assume that. The initial rotation is about the major axis, and it will continue to be so (in the absence of torque, and since you were already rotating about the major axis). Instead, since $\omega_2=\omega_3=0$, your equations for the evolution of the angular momentum don't require the moments of inertia to be the same.